# Singleton vs Static Preference and Defect

Tags: java, static, singleton, oop

When we want deploy Web Application should we use singleton Object or use Static instead of?
what is the bottleneck for use each of them?
I should know about Memory Problem , Concurrency problem and ... .

P.S: what happen for the class that was just readable (should use static or  Singleton)

P.S 2: what happen for the class that was readable and writable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it appears in your case a singleton / static methods would both work. I take it in both cases your helper methods are pure and do not use or need any state. In the end using a singleton gives you a few extra options such as the possibility to mock. By using a class rather than static helpers the possibility exists to evolve the design or perhaps substitute a different strategy etc some time in the future. With static helpers your pretty much stuck.

Since your methods are pure concurrency will not and cannot be a problem as no state is shared.

Comment: that's right, but if use static method in my web application is it possible I encounter problem later?
some where I read it's better don't use static in web application.

Answer (score 2):

Static: A single instance shared among all threads - any access to the static member will 
return the same instance.  There are no restrictions on creating *other* instances of the same type.

Singleton: A single instance for the entire application.  No other instances of this type can be created within the application.

Comment: An "all static" class is strange.  There's no "thing" represented by an instance of the class.  If there's no "thing", why have a class definition in the first place?

Comment: I meant "static instance" not "all static class".  An all static class does have some usage though for organizational purposes.